# MySQL group_concat returning all values instead of values per column

Tags: mysql

For example, I am using the world.sql database and here is a short sample of what it looks like:

```
CountryCode:char(3) Language:char(30) IsOfficial:enum('T', 'F') Percentage:float(4,1)
```

There will be several entries for each country code, looking like so:

```
ABW Dutch T 5.3
ABW English T 9.5
```

My goal is the following: I want to get all the official languages for a CountryCode.  I.e, if that is all the country codes for ABW I want it to return:

```
ABW Dutch|English
```

Here is my MySQL query:

```
SELECT
  CountryCode,
  group_concat(top.offlanguages SEPARATOR "|") AS "Official Languages"
FROM (
  SELECT
    CountryCode,
    Language AS offlanguages
  FROM CountryLanguage
  WHERE IsOfficial = 'T'
  GROUP BY CountryCode
) top
```

For some reason it returns every single possible language under the ABW CountryCode, and I cannot figure out why.

I.e, it returns something like this:

ABW Dutch|English|Arabic|...(on and on and on)

Comment: @AzizShaikh Where is the need to use another query for FROM part of main query? It can be done without that. Right?

Comment: Is the solution from AzizShaikh the best one?

Comment: @rakeshjain I believe you are correct but I have not tested that. You may edit and mention this in your answer. OP may test and use your suggestion after testing.

Comment: @Jason Aziz Shaikh also believes that my solution is better(See above comment). Can you verify the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this below query

```
SELECT CountryCode, group_concat(Language separator "|") as "Official Languages"
FROM CountryLanguage where IsOfficial = 'T' group by CountryCode
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `GROUP BY` is in the wrong place. It should be after `top`

Try this:

```
select CountryCode, group_concat(top.offlanguages separator "|") as "Official Languages" from (
  select CountryCode, Language as offlanguages 
  from CountryLanguage where IsOfficial = 'T'
) top group by CountryCode
```